# understanding recursive function python

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to understand what happens when this recursive function is called. The code is supposed to be a trace

```
def mysum(lower, upper, margin):
    blanks = ' ' * margin
    print blanks, lower, upper
    if lower > upper:
        print blanks, 0
        return 0
    else:
        result = lower + mysum(lower + 1, upper, margin + 4)
        print blanks, result, lower, margin
        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mysum(1, 4, 0)
```

the output reads

```
1 4
     2 4
         3 4
             4 4
                 5 4
                 0
             4 4 12
         7 3 8
     9 2 4
10 1 0
```

I don't understand why the function begins to unwind after it returns 0. Can you help me follow through what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code with comments helping you to begin to understand how the recursive function works.

```
def mysum(lower, upper, margin):
    blanks = ' ' * margin     # First time : margin = 0
                              # 2nd time : margin = 4
    print blanks, lower, upper   # first time : lower = 1, upper = 4
                                 # 2nd time : lower = 2, upper = 4
    if lower > upper:   # first time : go to else (& 2nd time, ... until lower =5)
        print blanks, 0
        return 0
    else:
        result = lower + mysum(lower + 1, upper, margin + 4)   # result is not directly calulated
                                                               # first it need to execute the call to
                                                               # the function, it will be the second call
        print blanks, result, lower, margin
        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mysum(1, 4, 0)     # First call of your function
```

When lower is at 5, there is no call to mysum and it returns 0.
So you unwind just one step : lower is at 4, and you where in the "else" part. You have to finish it

```
result = lower + mysum(lower + 1, upper, margin + 4)
print blanks, result, lower, margin
return result
```

with lower = 4 and the last call returned 0. The result = 4.
And you unwind another step : lower is at 3, and the call just before returned a 4, so the new result is 7. This value is returned.

Now, lower = 3, you do the same, for lower = 2, lower = 1.

You can see that 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10. And it is the result of your function.
I hope that I helped you, tell me if you don't understand, maybe can I find another way to explain ... :/

Answer (score 0):

In brief, you always make a recursive call before you reach a `return` statement, until you reach the base case. Then, you always reach a `return` statement before you reach another recursive call (trivially so, since there is only one recursive call).

Answer (score 0):

When one call of the function returns 0 ("bottoms out"), there might be many other calls to the function on the stack, waiting to proceed. When the recursion bottoms out, control returns to the last-but-one function on the stack. It finishes its work and returns, and control returns to the next earlier function on the stack. This continues until all the calls to `mysum` have been removed from the stack, in reverse order to the order on which they were put on the stack.

Maybe you understood all that already :) If so, please clarify what you mean by "why the function begins to unwind."

Comment: I initially thought that after the function reached the base case it would terminate, I did not realize that it had some some other calls left on the call stack

Answer (score 0):

I think a useful observation here is that the first five lines are printed before any of the nested calls returns. This all happens in the first part of the function body:

`print` - check condition - go to `else` - and go to beginning again, one level deeper.

When `0` is printed, the deepest call returns, so the second-deepest `result` gets calculated. Then the `print` from the next line occurs - and it's the first line with 3 numbers in it. Then you hit another `return`, so another `result` is calculated, etc. The consecutive returns correspond to earlier calls - thus they have less `blanks`.